# C++ Code generation and template specialization

Tags: c++, template-specialization

Does a C++ compiler generates code if a function template or a class template is specialized but not actually used? I know it will not, if not specialized (function or class template) and not used. 
--Thanks

Comment: When processing the translation unit that defines template specialization, the compiler cannot know whether or not it's used in some other translation unit. So it has no choice but to generate code for it; but then a decent linker would discard functions that are never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the compiler may choose to eliminate your specialization since it's elimination would not affect the observable behavior of your program. See the [as-if rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if). Compilers generally provide facilities for exporting symbols such that they are preserved even if unused.

Comment: Thank you Andrieux's for pointing out to "as-if rule". I understood few other cases where generated code could be eleminated by the compiler.